# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\xa0-'

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a huge dataframe and trying to groupby the data. My data looks like this:

| Date | Location | Value | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2010 | ABC | 1 | A1 |
| 01-02-2010 | ABC | 2 | A1 |
| 01-03-2010 | ABC | 3 | A1 |
| 01-04-2010 | ABC | 4 | A1 |

I am trying to groupby using:

```
df=df.groupby(['Date','Location'], as_index = False).agg({'Value':np.sum ,'type':'first'})
```

However, I am getting the following error:

invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\xa0-'

The Value col seems to have some odd values hindering the sum process. My dataframe has around 50 million rows and can't inspect the data using excel or notebook to figure out what these values are.

I have already cleaned the data using the following:

```
todroplist = ['-'," -",'- ', ' -',' - ','-',' -','0','NaN','','<NA>']

df= df[~df['Value'].isin(todroplist)]
```

I have tried to change the data type to int using the below but I also get the same error:

```
df.value=df.value.astype(str).astype(int)
```

Comment: You could add `'\xa0-'` to your droplist :)

Comment: For what it's worth, '\xa0' is Pythonesque for a non-breaking space. So '\xa0-' is the same as ' -' (which is already in you cleaning list) but with a non-breaking space.

Answer (score 0):

> My dataframe has around 50 million rows and can't inspect the data using excel or notebook to figure out what these values are

Yes you can :)

**How to debug?**

Use `pd.to_numeric`

Setup a MRE:

```
data = {'Date': ['01-01-2010', '01-02-2010', '01-03-2010', '01-04-2010'],
        'Location': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC'],
        'Value': [1, 2, '\xa0-3', 4],
        'type': ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output:
         Date Location Value type
0  01-01-2010      ABC     1   A1
1  01-02-2010      ABC     2   A1
2  01-03-2010      ABC    -3   A1  # Everything looks right but...
3  01-04-2010      ABC     4   A1
```

Try to convert `Value` column to numeric and extract NaN:

```
>>> df[pd.to_numeric(df['Value'], errors='coerce').isna()]
         Date Location Value type
2  01-03-2010      ABC    -3   A1
```

Now you can check your probably small subset of rows:

```
>>> df.loc[2, 'Value']
'\xa0-3'
```